CSS-Tailwind : Unable to overflow the long flex div within parent div to create a slide effect
The div(scroll-content) contains a long list of images that I want to hide under "scroller" div, so that I can place arrow buttons to create a slide effect. But the flex box is expanding to more than 100% of the container. This is within a Next JS application
let products = [{
  name:"sample 1",
  imageUrl:"https://picsum.photos/536/354"
}];

const Home = async () => {
return (
  <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center w-full">
    
    <div className="px-2">
      {" "}
      <div className="w-full mt-3">
        <span className="text-lg font-bold">Top picks</span>
      </div>
      <div id="scroller" className="w-full overflow-hidden z-10">
        <div id="scroll-content" className="flex z-0">
          <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
            <img
              className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
              alt={products[0].name}
              src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
            />
          </div>
          {/* Repeat the above div for other images */}
          <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
            <img
              className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
              alt={products[0].name}
              src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
            />
          </div>
          {/* Add more divs as needed */}
          <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
            <img
              className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
              alt={products[0].name}
              src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
            <img
              className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
              alt={products[0].name}
              src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
            <img
              className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
              alt={products[0].name}
              src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
            <img
              className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
              alt={products[0].name}
              src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
            <img
              className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
              alt={products[0].name}
              src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
            <img
              className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
              alt={products[0].name}
              src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
            <img
              className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
              alt={products[0].name}
              src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
            <img
              className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
              alt={products[0].name}
              src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
            <img
              className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
              alt={products[0].name}
              src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
            <img
              className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
              alt={products[0].name}
              src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="w-full mt-3">
        <span className="text-lg font-bold">Quick Links</span>
      </div>{" "}
    </div>
  </main>
);
};

export default Home;

I have tried inline-block and grid but still I cannot attain the desired functionality. Grid overlaps the internal divs on each other, inline-block wraps.

You'd want to apply max-width: 100% via the max-w-full class to the div.p-2 element. The overflowing children causes this element to be wider than the viewport, causing the elements to not display as desired.


let products = [
  {
    name: 'sample 1',
    imageUrl: 'https://picsum.photos/536/354',
  },
];

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center w-full">
      <div className="px-2 max-w-full">
        {' '}
        <div className="w-full mt-3">
          <span className="text-lg font-bold">Top picks</span>
        </div>
        <div id="scroller" className="w-full overflow-hidden z-10">
          <div id="scroll-content" className="flex z-0">
            <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
              <img
                className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
                alt={products[0].name}
                src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
              />
            </div>
            {/* Repeat the above div for other images */}
            <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
              <img
                className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
                alt={products[0].name}
                src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
              />
            </div>
            {/* Add more divs as needed */}
            <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
              <img
                className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
                alt={products[0].name}
                src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
              <img
                className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
                alt={products[0].name}
                src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
              <img
                className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
                alt={products[0].name}
                src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
              <img
                className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
                alt={products[0].name}
                src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
              <img
                className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
                alt={products[0].name}
                src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
              <img
                className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
                alt={products[0].name}
                src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
              <img
                className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
                alt={products[0].name}
                src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
              <img
                className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
                alt={products[0].name}
                src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
              <img
                className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
                alt={products[0].name}
                src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="inline-block h-[10rem] w-[10rem] flex-shrink-0">
              <img
                className="h-full max-w-full rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg"
                alt={products[0].name}
                src={`${products[0].imageUrl}`}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="w-full mt-3">
          <span className="text-lg font-bold">Quick Links</span>
        </div>{' '}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<Home />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-QVs8Lo43F9lSuBykadDb0oSXDL/BbZ588urWVCRwSIoewQv/Ewg1f84mK3U790bZ0FfhFa1YSQUmIhG+pIRKeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-6a1107rTlA4gYpgHAqbwLAtxmWipBdJFcq8y5S/aTge3Bp+VAklABm2LO+Kg51vOWR9JMZq1Ovjl5tpluNpTeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div id="app"></div>



